# Adding multiple class level attributes c#

Tags: c#

I want to add a property to the Node which is optional for the user to set.
How do I add another class level attribute aside from the one which already exists ?

**VirtualName** - this would give users the ability to name the node whatever they want.
I already implemented the ClassName. I will eventually want to add other class object level attributes like color and icon.

```
namespace NodeDemo
{
    [NodeAttribute("DemoNode")]
    public class DemoNode
    {
        [InputPinAttribute("Radius")]
        public int Radius { get; set; }

        [InputPinAttribute("Width Segments")]
        public int WidthSegs { get; set; }

        [InputPinAttribute("Height Segments")]
        public int HeightSegs { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I find myself asking why you wouldn't use a more conventional means of setting a default value... perhaps by setting it in the constructor.

Comment: Updates to specify question.

Comment: I really have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: You can add as many attributes to a class as you want. One follows the other, immediately before the declaration of the class. The same applies for properties and parameters.

Comment: Spender that is what I was curious to know. How would I retrive a specific one if I were to have two of them stacked. For example NodeAttribute(red) and below that NodeAttribute("Demo Node"). How can I collect the one for color?

Comment: If you describe how you (as person) would want to distinguish `NodeAttribute(string)` from `NodeAttribute(string)` (i.e. string with space is special, must have order, something else) than such implementation can be represented as code. In current state it is not answerable.

Comment: Side note: @JokerMartini, remember that if you want to direct comment to particular person like "Spender" you should add @ in front of the name, otherwise there is no notification to that person.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add as many as you want:

```
namespace NodeDemo
{
    public class ColorAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public string Color {get;set;}
        public ColorAttribute(string color)
        {
            Color = color;
        }
    }

    [NodeAttribute("DemoNode")]
    [ColorAttribute("Red")] 
    public class DemoNode
    {
      ... 
    } 
}
```

You can latter check attribute using `Type.Attributes` property

```
string color = null;
Type myType = typeof(DemoNode);
ColorAttribute cAttribute = (ColorAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(myType, typeof(ColorAttribute));
if (cAttribute != null)
{
    color = cAttribute.Color;
}
```

Comment: How do I collect a specific attribute once it's added. Could you show an example using Color and Name each as class level attributes ? Then show how you'd collect it.

Comment: could you create an example ?

Comment: I edited answer with example for retrieving attribute data.